# Find referencing a document field in mongo

Tags: mongodb, perl, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents with this structure:

```
{
  'travellers': [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ],
  ...
  'authorized-travellers': {
    'a' => {
        creator => 'admin',
        authorized => true,
        when => '2016-18-10 22:45:45',
    },
    'd' => {
        creator => 'admin',  
        authorized => false,
        when => '2016-17-10 12:44:00',
    },
  }
}
```

and I need a query to locate all documents that has pending travellers authorizations.

A travel (document) has pending travellers authorizations if travellers.count is less than 'authorized-travellers' keys.

In this example this travel has 2 pending authorizations: b and c.

If this possible (in perl) or I need to perform the query manually?
How?

Thanks

Comment: Ok, can you let me know how do it?

Comment: @simbabque: Eagerly waiting to learn the differences between them from you.

Comment: @ssr1012 _Perl_ is the name of the language. _perl_ is the name of the Perl compiler (the binary that runs Perl code). _PERL_ has nothing to do with the Perl language. You can read [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Name), but the most important source is [perlfaq1](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f), where it says _But never write "PERL", because perl is not an acronym._.

Comment: @simbabque: Corrected myself. thanks.

Comment: [May be this will help you](http://perlmaven.com/getting-started-with-mongodb-using-perl-insert-and-update)

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple way to do that server-side.  You might be able to construct a [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) function.

If possible, I would look to revise the schema to keep the pending count (or boolean flag) as an invariant in the document itself.  When updating `travellers` and `authorized-travellers`, update the `pending` count/flag as an atomic operation at the same time.  Then the query for pending authorizations would be trivial.

To update existing documents to add the invariant, you'll need to be careful about data races if these are updated frequently.

If a schema change isn't possible, then looping over the documents client-side and checking individually is straightforward, if inefficient.  If there's a lot of documents and a lot of data per document, make sure you only project back only the fields you need.

Hope these ideas help.